# How to generate VirtualMachineError in java?

Tags: java

I just wanted to do some research and wanted to generate the VirtualMachineError. 
Can any one tell me how can I generate VirtualMachineError?

Answer (score 2):

A `StackOverflowError` is a `VirtualMachineError`, so you can provoke such an error by running a recursion without a basecase. (But why?)

Comment: I was going trough a topic named Exception Handling at that time there was written that we should not throw an Error/Throwable. So there was a line that what if the code generates the VirtualMachineError. That's why I wanted to know.